# Close and restart application with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, reboot

I need a autohotkey script that closes and restart a program immediately, for example Screamer Radio, `screamer.exe`.

I use `^#Numpad7::run` to run `screamer.exe`

```
^#Numpad7::run C:\Programmi\Screamer Radio\screamer.exe
```

but I need to restart immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
^#Numpad7::
Process, Close, screamer.exe ; close the radio
run C:\Programmi\Screamer Radio\screamer.exe; re-open
```